# Setting up S3 logging in Airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, airflow

This is driving me nuts.

I'm setting up airflow in a cloud environment. I have one server running the scheduler and the webserver and one server as a celery worker, and I'm using airflow 1.8.0.

Running jobs works fine. What *refuses* to work is logging.

I've set up the correct path in airflow.cfg on both servers:

> remote_base_log_folder = s3://my-bucket/airflow_logs/
>
> remote_log_conn_id = s3_logging_conn

I've set up s3_logging_conn in the airflow UI, with the access key and the secret key as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow).

I checked the connection using

> s3 = airflow.hooks.S3Hook('s3_logging_conn')
>
> s3.load_string('test','test',bucket_name='my-bucket')

This *works* on both servers. So the connection is properly set up. Yet all I get whenever I run a task is

> *** Log file isn't local.
>
> *** Fetching here: http://*******
>
> *** Failed to fetch log file from worker.
>
> *** Reading remote logs...
>
> Could not read logs from s3://my-bucket/airflow_logs/my-dag/my-task/2018-02-15T21:46:47.577537

I tried manually uploading the log following the expected conventions and the webserver still can't pick it up - so the problem is on both ends. I'm at a loss at what to do, everything I've read so far tells me this *should* be working. I'm close to just installing the 1.9.0 which I hear changes logging and see if I'm more lucky.

UPDATE: I made a clean install of Airflow 1.9 and followed the specific instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194903/5378460).

Webserver won't even start now with the following error:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: section/key [core/remote_logging] not found in config

There *is* an explicit reference to this section in [this config template](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py).

So I tried removing it and just loading the S3 handler without checking first and I got the following error message instead:

> Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 384, in resolve:
>
> self.importer(used)
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>
> 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.RedirectStdHandler';
>
> 'airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin' is not a package

I get the feeling that this shouldn't be *this* hard.

Any help would be much appreciated, cheers

Comment: I have now reinstalled everything, generated new credentials *and* upgraded to Airflow 1.9 and the problem persists.

Comment: Please update the logs with the errors from Airflow 1.9, it should work and some users are actually using this in production.

Comment: Done, added the new errors.

Comment: Just a side note, the current template incubator-airflow/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py present in master branch contains a reference to the class "airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler", which is not present in apache-airflow==1.9.0 python package.
The fix is simple - use rather this base template: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/v1-9-stable/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py After having done that, follow all other instructions in the [mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194903/9979495). Note that this tweak regards s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

1. upgraded to 1.9
2. ran the steps described [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow/48194903#48194903)
3. added

   > [core]
   >
   > remote_logging = True

   to airflow.cfg
4. ran

   > pip install --upgrade airflow[log]

Everything's working fine now.