# How to programmatically set up Airflow 1.10 logging with localstack s3 endpoint?

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, docker-compose, airflow, localstack

In attempt to setup airflow logging to localstack s3 buckets, for local and kubernetes dev environments, I am following the [airflow documentation for logging to s3](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/howto/write-logs.html). To give a little context, [localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) is a local AWS cloud stack with AWS services including s3 running locally.

I added the following environment variables to my airflow containers [similar to this other stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow#answer-48194903) in attempt to log to my local s3 buckets. This is what I added to `docker-compose.yaml` for all airflow containers:

```
       - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING=True
       - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://local-airflow-logs
       - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=MyS3Conn
       - AIRFLOW__CORE__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS=False
```

I've also added my localstack s3 creds to `airflow.cfg`

```sh
[MyS3Conn]
aws_access_key_id = foo
aws_secret_access_key = bar
aws_default_region = us-east-1
host = http://localstack:4572    # s3 port. not sure if this is right place for it
```

Additionally, I've installed apache-airflow[hooks], and apache-airflow[s3], though it's not clear which one is really needed based on the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/1.10.1/howto/write-logs.html).

I've followed the steps in [a previous stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48817258/setting-up-s3-logging-in-airflow) in attempt verify if the S3Hook can write to my localstack s3 instance:

```py
from airflow.hooks import S3Hook
s3 = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='MyS3Conn')
s3.load_string('test','test',bucket_name='local-airflow-logs')
```

But I get `botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

After adding credentials to airflow console under `/admin/connection/edit` as depicted: 
[image]
this is the new exception, `botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.` is returned. [Other people have encountered this same issue](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/1568) and it may have been related to networking.

Regardless, a programatic setup is needed, not a manual one.

I was able to access the bucket using a standalone Python script (entering AWS credentials explicitly with boto), but it needs to work as part of airflow.

Is there a proper way to set up host / port / credentials for `S3Hook` by adding `MyS3Conn` to `airflow.cfg`?

Based on the [airflow s3 hooks source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/58c3542ed25061320ce61dbe0adf451a44c738dd/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/s3.py), it seems a custom s3 URL may not yet be supported by airflow. However, based on the airflow [aws_hook source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/58c3542ed25061320ce61dbe0adf451a44c738dd/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/hooks/aws_hook.py) (parent) it seems it should be possible to set the endpoint_url including port, and it should be read from `airflow.cfg`.

I am able to inspect and write to my s3 bucket in localstack using boto alone. Also, `curl http://localstack:4572/local-mochi-airflow-logs` returns the contents of the bucket from the airflow container. And `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 ls` returns `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4572/"`.

What other steps might be needed to log to localstack s3 buckets from airflow running in docker, with automated setup and is this even supported yet?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're supposed to use `localhost` not `localstack` for the endpoint, e.g. `host = http://localhost:4572`.

In Airflow 1.10 you can override the endpoint on a per-connection basis but unfortunately it only supports one endpoint at a time so you'd be changing it for *all* AWS hooks using the connection. To override it, edit the relevant connection and in the "Extra" field put:

```
{"host": "http://localhost:4572"}
```

I believe this will fix it?

Comment: This helped me in solving the problem with another provider.

Comment: I confirm I got this working with Airflow v2.2.1.

To be 100% clear, the "host" field in the form I left empty and the above json is put in the "Extra" field. I also had to put a nonsense login and password to avoid a `NoCredentialsError` exception

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make this work by referring to [this guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#generating-a-connection-uri). Basically you need to create a connection using the Connection class and pass the credentials that you need, in my case I needed `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, REGION_NAME` to make this work.  Use this function as a `python_callable` in a `PythonOperator` which should be the first part of the DAG.

```py
import os
import json
from airflow.models.connection import Connection
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowFailException

def _create_connection(**context):
    """
    Sets the connection information about the environment using the Connection
    class instead of doing it manually in the Airflow UI
    """
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
    AWS_SESSION_TOKEN = os.getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN")
    REGION_NAME = os.getenv("REGION_NAME")
    credentials = [
        AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        REGION_NAME,
    ]
    if not credentials or any(not credential for credential in credentials):
        raise AirflowFailException("Environment variables were not passed")

    extras = json.dumps(
        dict(
            aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
            aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
            region_name=REGION_NAME,
        ),
    )
    try:
        Connection(
            conn_id="s3_con",
            conn_type="S3",
            extra=extras,
        )
    except Exception as e:
        raise AirflowFailException(
            f"Error creating connection to Airflow :{e!r}",
        )
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29623455)

Comment: @dm2 alright I updated the answer to be more descriptive.