# Airflow Error - ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file.processor'

Tags: airflow, aws-codebuild, airflow-scheduler

I am running airflow 1.9.0 in **codebuild** container with Python 3.6.5, we execute the following commands and get error

```
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file.processor': 
  'FileProcessorHandler' object has no attribute 'log'
```

sudo sh scripts/setup.sh

```
AIRFLOW_HOME="$(cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
export PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=True

cat <<EOF > $AIRFLOW_HOME/.env
PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=True
AIRFLOW_HOME=$AIRFLOW_HOME
EOF

cat <<EOF > $AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.cfg

[core]
airflow_home = $AIRFLOW_HOME
dags_folder = $AIRFLOW_HOME/dags
base_log_folder = $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs
remote_log_conn_id =
encrypt_s3_logs = False
logging_level = INFO
logging_config_class =
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
executor = SequentialExecutor
sql_alchemy_conn = sqlite:///$AIRFLOW_HOME/airflow.db
sql_alchemy_pool_size = 5
sql_alchemy_pool_recycle = 3600
parallelism = 32
dag_concurrency = 16
dags_are_paused_at_creation = True
non_pooled_task_slot_count = 128
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
load_examples = False
plugins_folder = $AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins
fernet_key = QfQ90TaCFkE9fSLJnoikJCRxj4cnqFX69D1_Lbnhinw=
donot_pickle = False
dagbag_import_timeout = 30
task_runner = BashTaskRunner
default_impersonation =
security =
unit_test_mode = False
task_log_reader = file.task
enable_xcom_pickling = True
killed_task_cleanup_time = 60

[cli]
api_client = airflow.api.client.local_client
endpoint_url = http://localhost:8080

[api]
auth_backend = airflow.api.auth.backend.default

[operators]
default_owner = Airflow
default_cpus = 1
default_ram = 512
default_disk = 512
default_gpus = 0


[webserver]
base_url = http://localhost:8080
web_server_host = 0.0.0.0
web_server_port = 8080
web_server_ssl_cert =
web_server_ssl_key =
web_server_worker_timeout = 120
worker_refresh_batch_size = 1
worker_refresh_interval = 30
secret_key = temporary_key
workers = 4
worker_class = sync
access_logfile = -
error_logfile = -
expose_config = False
authenticate = False
filter_by_owner = False
owner_mode = user
dag_default_view = tree
dag_orientation = LR
demo_mode = False
log_fetch_timeout_sec = 5
hide_paused_dags_by_default = False
page_size = 100

[email]
email_backend = airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp

[dask]
cluster_address = 127.0.0.1:8786

[scheduler]
job_heartbeat_sec = 5
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
run_duration = -1
min_file_process_interval = 0
dag_dir_list_interval = 300
print_stats_interval = 30
child_process_log_directory = $AIRFLOW_HOME/logs/scheduler
scheduler_zombie_task_threshold = 300
catchup_by_default = True
max_tis_per_query = 0
statsd_on = False
statsd_host = localhost
statsd_port = 8125
statsd_prefix = airflow
max_threads = 2
authenticate = False

[github_enterprise]
api_rev = v3

[admin]
hide_sensitive_variable_fields = True

EOF

pipenv --three install
. $(pwd)/.venv/bin/activate
```

I have the Pipfile in this way, in which I install all the packages to run airflow, it executes ok.

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
apache-airflow = {extras = ["celery", "crypto", "jdbc", "postgres", "s3", 
"slack", "ssh", "redis", "log"], version = "==1.9.0"}
pymongo = "~=3.6.1"
boto3 = "~=1.7.40"
retrying = "~=1.3.3"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

After that I have my buildspec.yml

```
  - sudo sh scripts/setup.sh
  - . $(pwd)/.venv/bin/activate
  - airflow initdb
```

And I get this error when I tried to execute any airflow command, I do not find anything to try to solve this problem that I have

```
[Container] 2018/07/31 19:04:07 Running command airflow initdb
Unable to load the config, contains a configuration error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 558, in configure
handler = self.configure_handler(handlers[name])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 731, in configure_handler
result = factory(**kwargs)
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 50, in __init__
self._symlink_latest_log_directory()
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- packages/airflow/utils/log/file_processor_handler.py", line 110, in _symlink_latest_log_directory
self.log.warning(
AttributeError: 'FileProcessorHandler' object has no attribute 'log'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/bin/airflow", line 16, in 
<module>
from airflow import configuration
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
from airflow import settings
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/settings.py", line 148, in <module>
configure_logging()
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 75, in configure_logging
raise e
File "/codebuild/output/src571717869/src/.venv/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/airflow/logging_config.py", line 70, in configure_logging
dictConfig(logging_config)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 795, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/config.py", line 566, in configure
'%r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'file.processor': 'FileProcessorHandler' object has no attribute 'log'

[Container] 2018/07/31 19:04:07 Command did not exit successfully airflow initdb exit status 1
```

Comment: I suspect this might be connected to `logging_config_class` being empty in your config, but I have used this build platform before.

Comment: @tobi6 I currently have my `logging_config_class` empty in my airflow.cfg that I copied from the airflow_default.cfg. Is there a default out-of-box value we can put in this config or do we have to go through the process of configuring a logging class and then setting it's path here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow/48194903#48194903)?

Comment: Never mind I am looking over the log changes mentioned here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#logging-update

Comment: Update: Once I set the `logging_config_class` this error went away for me.

Comment: Note for anyone using Airflow 1.10, you'll need to set that `logging_config_class` as mentioned in Kyle's link: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#airflow-110

Comment: I followed the instructions but now getting the following error:
`ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'processor': Cannot resolve 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler': dlopen(/Users/arikliber/miniconda3/envs/py36-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil/_psutil_osx.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___CFConstantStringClassReference` any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I change the way to execute the Airflow and it works and also some detail about configuration:

SO: Ubuntu 16.04
Python 3.6.5

I remove the following lines from the setup.sh and let it into the buildspec.yml

```
pipenv --three install
. $(pwd)/.venv/bin/activate
```

Also is better to use `pipenv run` instead of `pipenv shell` for my execution

(http://witkowskibartosz.com/blog/pipenv_run_vs_pipenv_shell.html#.W9e012hKjIU)

#### Buildspec.yml

```
- bash scripts/setup.sh
- for var in $(cat .env) ; do export $var ; done
- pipenv --three install
- pipenv run airflow initdb
- pipenv run airflow list_dags
- pipenv run airflow list_tasks ${dag}
- pipenv run airflow backfill -s $(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%Y-%m-%d') ${dag}
- aws s3 cp --recursive --region us-east-1 $(pwd)/logs/ ${bucket_logs}
```