# Error while install airflow: By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs a GPL

Tags: airflow

Getting the following error after running `pip install airflow[postgres]` command:

```
> raise RuntimeError("By default one of Airflow's dependencies installs
> a GPL "
> 
> RuntimeError: By default one of Airflow's dependencies  installs a GPL
> dependency (unidecode). To avoid this dependency set
> SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes in your environment when you install
> or upgrade Airflow. To force installing the GPL version set
> AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE
```

I am trying to install in Debian 9

Comment: So, did you set either `SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE` or `AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE` as stated in the message before installing?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. I have exported those environment variable.

Comment: Both? You should decide for one and set that.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Try the following:

```
export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes
```

OR

```
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
```

Using `export` makes the environment variable available to all the subprocesses.

Also, make sure you are using `pip install apache-airflow[postgres]` and not `pip install airflow[postgres]`

Which should you use: if using AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE, airflow will install a dependency that is under GPL license, which means you won't be able to distribute your resulting application commercially. If that's a problem for you, go for SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE.

Comment: my problem was solved by the first of those 2x suggestions, thanks kaxil

Comment: @kaxil What is the difference between choosing one over the other?

Comment: @Newskooler Answer is edited to include that info :)

Comment: @kaxil..Could you help me with this? I am having issue while installing it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987782/facing-issue-while-configuring-mysql-with-apache-airflow-in-hadoop

Answer (score 31):

If you are installing using **sudo** run **one** of these commands:

```
sudo AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes pip3 install apache-airflow
```

**OR**

```
sudo SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes pip3 install apache-airflow
```

**NOTE**: If `pip3` (python3) does not work for you, try `pip` command.
The `pip` command can be pointing to python2 or python3 installation depending on your system. Verify this by running `pip --version`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The first command worked.
 (Note: Normal pip3 install apache-airflow was not working for me)

Comment: This worked for me (not the accepted answer) with pip (not pip3)

Answer (score 10):

Windows users can use the command below before installing apache-airflow:

```
$ set AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes
```

then

```
$ pip install apache-airflow
```

Answer (score 3):

Below command should install apache-airflow and lets you pull changes into PyCharm for building DAGs and coding for Airflow.

`SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes`

`pip install apache-airflow`

Answer (score 3):

In case you are installing the airflow on Windows and through Python terminal then you need to write this:

> Set SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
>
> pip install apache-airflow[postgres]

It worked with me after I struggled with trying many other options. Hope this will work with you too.

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you are installing using sudo you can use:

```
export AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE='yes'
sudo -E pip3 install apache-airflow
```

(or use `SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE`)

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in your python terminal: `SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes pip install apache-airflow==1.10.0`

Answer (score 1):

Use below command to install **apache-airflow**

```
sudo SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes \
pip install apache-airflow[async,devel,celery,crypto,druid,gcp_api,jdbc,hdfs,hive,kerberos,ldap,password,postgres,qds,rabbitmq,s3,samba,slack]
```