# What's the correct format of connection creation for Azure Blob Storage in Airflow?

Tags: azure, scheduler, airflow

Airflow have a notion of creation of connection which can be used by hooks? We wanted to remotely push logs to Azure Blob Storage for that we need to setup a connection for Blob Storage, any information would be very helpful. I'm looking for information similar to what someone has mentioned for S3 here.

[setting up s3 for logs in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow/48194903#answer-44796247)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the key in login field, and secret key in the password And leave extra empty