# Airflow writes and reads from S3 successfully but won't load S3 logs on docker-compose up

Tags: docker-compose, airflow

I'm using puckle's airflow docker ([github link](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow)) with docker-compose-LocalExecutor. The project is deployed through CI/CD on EC2 instance so my airflow doesn't run on a persistent server. (**Every push on master it gets launched afresh**). I know i'm losing some great features but in my setup everything is configured by bash script and/or enviroment variables.
My setup is similiar to this answer setup: [Similar setup answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47947127/4599272)

**I'm running on version 1.10.6**, so the old method of adding `config/__init__.py` and `config/log_class.py` is not needed anymore.

#### Changes I made on the original repository code:

1. I added some enviroment variables and changed the build mode on `docker-compose -f docker-compose-LocalExecutor` to write/save logs on S3 and build from local Dockerfile:

   ```
   webserver:
       build: .
       environment:
           - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING=True
           - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=aws_default
           - AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://path/to/logs
           - AIRFLOW_CONN_AWS_DEFAULT=s3://key:password
   ```
2. I changed `Dockerfile` on **line 59** to install s3 plugin as showed below:

   ```
   && pip install apache-airflow[s3,crypto,celery,password,postgres,hive,jdbc,mysql,ssh${AIRFLOW_DEPS:+,}${AIRFLOW_DEPS}]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION} \
   ```

**Those configurations works fine, the logs are written and read successfully from S3 as showed below:**

[image]

#### My problem is:

If I run `docker-compose down` and `docker-compose up` the UI appear as the dags have never run before (The UI won't load the dag's remote logs):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that runned events are not rebuilded from logs files. All the metadata (running events, users, xconn, etc) are stored in a external DataBase.
Once a configured a connection to a external database everything worked fine!