# How do I load new Airflow configuration?

Tags: airflow

I'm using Airflow for my ETL and now I want to make some changes (`donot_pickle=True`) in my Airflow config. How do I load the new config? Using:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build
```

Just updates the container config. Am I forced to recreate the whole thing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting up s3 for logs in airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780736/setting-up-s3-for-logs-in-airflow)

Comment: Where do I run "export AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE=True"? Almost there...

Answer (score 4):

I will assume you're using puckel's docker-compose deployment (https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) because it's the most popular one and you didn't specify any.

You can share any airflow configuration variable such as **AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE** as an environment variable on each of the services specified inside your **docker-compose.yml** files.

Let's see how that can be accomplish for the **scheduler** service of the celery-executor version, for example:

```
scheduler:
    ...
    environment:
        - LOAD_EX=n
        - EXECUTOR=Celery
        - AIRFLOW__CORE__DONOT_PICKLE=True
        - ...
    ...
```

Each environment value you specify in there will be made available to the service the next time its corresponding docker container gets restarted.