# How to output Airflow's scheduler log to stdout or S3 / GCS

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We're running Airflow cluster using [puckel/airflow](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) docker image with docker-compose. Airflow's scheduler container outputs its logs to `/usr/local/airflow/logs/scheduler`.

The problem is that the log files are not rotated and disk usage increases until the disk gets full. [Dag for cleaning up the log directory](https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-maintenance-dags/blob/master/log-cleanup/airflow-log-cleanup.py) is available but the DAG run on worker node and log directory on scheduler container is not cleaned up.

I'm looking for the way to output scheduler log to stdout or S3/GCS bucket but unable to find out. Is there any to output the scheduler log to stdout or S3/GCS bucket?

Answer (score 3):

Finally I managed to output scheduler's log to stdout.

[Here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html#advanced-configuration) you can find how to use custom logger of Airflow. The default logging config is available at [github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py).

What you have to do is.

(1) Create custom logger class to `${AIRFLOW_HOME}/config/log_config.py`.

```py
# Setting processor (scheduler, etc..) logs output to stdout
# Referring https://www.astronomer.io/guides/logging
# This file is created following https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/logging-monitoring/logging-tasks.html#advanced-configuration

from copy import deepcopy
from airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings import DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG
import sys

LOGGING_CONFIG = deepcopy(DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG)
LOGGING_CONFIG["handlers"]["processor"] = {
    "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
    "formatter": "airflow",
    "stream": sys.stdout,
}
```

(2) Set `logging_config_class` property to `config.log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG` in `airflow.cfg`

```py
logging_config_class = config.log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG
```

(3) [Optional] Add $AIRFLOW_HOME to `PYTHONPATH` environment.

```sh
export "${PYTHONPATH}:~"
```

- Actually, you can set the path of `logging_config_class` to anything as long as the python is able to load the package.
- Setting handler.processor to `airflow.utils.log.logging_mixin.RedirectStdHandler` didn't work for me. It used too much memory.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing this out. It helped me to configure airflow tasks to log to stdout using k8s executor. Next comment includes my helm values (just in case anyone would find it helpful) (sorry about formatting, no idea how to paste code block into a comment).

Comment: ```yaml
config:
  logging:
    logging_config_class: airflow_local_settings.LOGGING_CONFIG

airflowLocalSettings: |-
  from copy import deepcopy
  from airflow.config_templates.airflow_local_settings import DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG
  import sys

  LOGGING_CONFIG = deepcopy(DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG)

  LOGGING_CONFIG['handlers']['stdout'] = {
    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    'stream': sys.stdout,
    'formatter': 'airflow',
    'filters': ['mask_secrets'],
  }

  LOGGING_CONFIG['loggers']['airflow.task']['handlers'] = [
    'stdout',
    'task',
  ]```

Comment: @faja if that worked for you, can you explain it a bit more and make an answer out of it? Seems to me to be a good alternative to what toshiya did

Answer (score 0):

`remote_logging=True` in airflow.cfg is the key.
Please check the thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48194903/11513936) for detailed steps.

Comment: `remote_logging=True` outputs *task* logs to S3/GCS. My problem is outputting *scheduler* logs to stdout or S3/GCS instead of to the local file.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the image with the following or do so in airflow.cfg

```
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOGGING=True
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=gcp_conn_id
ENV AIRFLOW__LOGGING__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=gs://bucket_name/AIRFLOW_LOGS
```

the gcp_conn_id should have the correct permission to create/delete objects in GCS